Is it possible to read steps synchronously on Android?
Is it possible to read either the daily total steps taken, or the steps since boot in a synchronous fashion on an android WearOS device?
The problem being that this data is only needed exactly once on app start.
Ideally without using Google Fitness or the newer APIs since this requires a login which is overkill for a simple app.

first: you don't need a login for google health. you can get the daily step count there, but not synchronous.
the step sensor on the other hand will give you the step since boot, but i'm not sure if it is giving you the count at the moment you register a listener.
